# run -i vs run -it?

Tags: bash, docker

I am using boot2docker on windows. I tried the following commands

```
  docker run -i centos /bin/bash

  docker run -it centos /bin/bash
```

Both provides same kind of execution. I read -i is interactive mode. -t is terminal mode. But i can able to execute commands like `pwd` and `ls` in both -i and -it. Only resulting UI is different.

Then whats the use of these two flags? Am i missing something?

Comment: Try a command which requires a TTY, like `sudo` or `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

`docker -i` gives you a non-interactive shell (`-i` means *interactive* for docker, not for bash inside it).

You can check this by running the following command (variable `$-` includes `i` if bash is interactive):

```
echo $- |grep i && echo i am interactive || echo i am non-interactive
```

This non-interactive bash doesn't display command prompt, it's difficult to determine when long-running command has finished its job,
you can't use command history,
and tty-based programs look like a mess.

Try `vim` (complains about `Output/Input is not a terminal`, looks and behaves weird) 
or some `rogue`-like game (for example, `crawl` simply refuses to work).

On the other hand, `docker -it` gives an ordinary interactive shell with command prompt (which you can tune via `$PS1`)
and command history (including `Ctrl-r`).
When a command finishes, it's clearly visible because of prompt, and tty-requiring programs work fine.

So, if you're going to manually type commands into the shell, use `docker -it`.